# Doctrine query result cache with API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

In Symfony, i used to enable query results cache this way:

Configuration in doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu

services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

Enabling result caching in entity repository:

```
$builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

$builder->setMaxResults(1);

return $builder
    ->getQuery()
    ->useQueryCache(true)
    ->setQueryCacheLifetime(43200)
    ->useResultCache(true)
    ->setResultCacheLifetime(21600)
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

I can't figure out what is the right way to implement query result cache using API Platform since i am not using the repositories manually.

Comment: You weren't able to figure it out using the docs ? https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/

Comment: Unless i'm wrong, this is more about setting a http cache, a full entity is retrieved faster from a http request if it has been queried before. Doctrine cache is not the same, it stores entities retrieved from the database and prevents doing requests. Of course, ideally i should use both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be the right way but maybe with extensions ?
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34463517)